# In Omaha Poker, can we use 0,1,3 or 4 hole cards when selecting the best 5 cards?

Tags: poker, poker-texas-holdem

According to Wikipedia, in Omaha, a player must use exactly two hole cards and three communal cards when selecting the best hand.

In Texas Hold'em Poker, it is possible to use only the communal cards without using any hole cards, if the communal cards alone give the best hand.

So, is Omaha different from Texas Hold'em, in the sense that an exact number of hole cards must be used in Omaha?

Comment: The Rules are the Rules. What about the Rules as you state them is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer you title question: No. You are obliged to use 2 and only 2 of your hole cards.

There are main 2 differences between Texas Hold'em and Omaha Hold'em.

1. The number of hole cards you have.
2. The number of hold cards you must use to create your final hand.

In Texas Hold'em you get 2 hole cards dealt to you, but are not required to use any of them to form your final 5 card hand.

In Omaha Hold'em you get 4 hole cards dealt to you, but are required to use 2 (and only 2) of them when forming your final 5 card hand.